# `np.gradient` has high variance for non-uniform spacing

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I encountered high variance in `np.gradient` for relatively smooth data.

Suppose we want to calculate `dx/dt`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([13.11149679, 13.2141427 , 13.37743691, 13.3934357 , 13.56163066,
       13.60207566, 13.69304133])
t = np.array([0.73065159, 0.74012055, 0.75911018, 0.7607452 , 0.77811468,
       0.78031837, 0.79046324])
x_grad = np.gradient(x, t)

plt.plot(t[1:], np.diff(x) / np.diff(t), 'xb', label="findiff")
plt.plot(t, x_grad, 'or', label = 'np.gradient')
plt.plot(t, x, '+g', label = "x")
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The noise in data seems to be amplified by a lot. How should we deal with this?

Comment: If that's the derivative, then that's the derivative. You can't make the derivative smoother without changing the data.

Comment: Also, your title says that `np.gradient` has a "high error". How does `np.gradient` compare to the true derivative? What prompts you to say that the error is high?

Comment: Fixed "high error" to "high variance". I'm trying to find ways to get smoother derivatives `dx/dt` relative to the smoothness of `x`, is what I'm saying.  So spline methods could be a suggestion

Comment: You mention wanting to reduce the variance and smoothness, but you're stuck with the information you have. You could potentially compute the derivative with a higher-order method, but they are annoying to develop when you have a nonuniform grid.

Comment: If you want a derivative at a point t, then take a segment around that point and fit it to a line or quadratic function. There will be a trade-off in choosing the radius of the interval, the longer the more noise is reduced. But if the radius is too large, the actual curvature of the exact function will intrude and give systematic errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Notes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html), `np.gradient()` calculates a second order approximation at each point, except at the boundaries.

`np.diff(x) / np.diff(t)` calculates the slope at each interval (n-1 values), while `gradient()` makes an estimation at each point (n values), yielding an intermediate value between the corresponding left and right interval slopes. The values are the same at the boundaries in both methods when using the default value for the `edge_order` parameter.

Comment: Yes I used `np.diff(x) / np.diff(x)` just to make a very simple approximation of gradient, and compare that to `np.gradient`, which does not seem to do much better. I guess what I'm asking is how we should deal with the increased variance in the gradient, and we know the variance in the target function is quite small as shown above.